# Taking data from a single form and saving in multiple models in loopback

Tags: database, loopbackjs, loopback

I am trying to take data from a single form that has the user credentials along with user details and store them in seperate models in loopback. I have created the required models and relations but I am confused on how to do this. 
 Does this happen automatically since the relations are specified or do i have to make use of the afterRemote method to do so ?

There are my models

```
    {
    "name": "userdetails",
    "base": "PersistedModel",
    "idInjection": true,
    "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
    },
    "properties": {
        "first_name": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        },
        "last_name": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        },
        "primary_contact": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        },
        "company_name": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        }
    },
    "validations": [],
    "relations": {
        "User": {
            "type": "belongsTo",
            "model": "user",
            "foreignKey": "userId"
        }
    },
    "acls": [],
    "methods": []
}
```

and the second model

```
{
"name": "user",
"plural": "users",
"base": "User",
"idInjection": true,
"options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
},
"properties": {},
"validations": [],
"relations": {
    "UserDetails": {
        "type": "hasOne",
        "model": "userdetails",
        "foreignKey": "userId"
    }
},
"acls": [{
    "accessType": "EXECUTE",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
    "permission": "DENY",
    "property": "GET"
}],
"methods": []
```

}

I have looked at the loopback angular admin project and am trying to use it as the reference point for this but so far I have been unsuccessful in figuring this out. Any pointers on this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Were you able to find anything for this?  I'm having the same questions too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer you might be looking for.  I asked about how to save on 3 different models through 1 endpoint.

[Save multiple models in loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340692/save-multiple-models-in-loopback/34353208#34353208)

In essence, you create a new `remoteMethod` endpoint that will allow you to save all your parameters you pass it.  You can't override much of the standard CRUD operations on the models

This new `remoteMethod` endpoint might also be more preferred so that you keep your standard `Create`/`Update` methods the way they are.